# Get reference count of reverse foreign key relations

Tags: foreign-key, information-schema

Image I have a simple `user` table like this:

```
ID|Name
-------
12|Foo
```

I want to know: How many reverse foreign key relations point to the user with ID `12`? I mean the number of rows which are a foreign key to `user` and contain the value `12`.

I use PostgresSQL, but a portable solution would be better ...

Comment: Do you want the number of tables, the number of rows per table or the total number of rows in all other tables that reference this row? Second, do you know the tables that have an FK that references `user` or is this (metadata info) needed to be found out by code?

Comment: @ypercube good comment! I updated the question: I mean the number of rows which are a foreign key to `user` and contain the value `12`.

Comment: There is a similar question at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213052/search-entire-database210-tables-for-a-unique-id-pk-and-get-the-table-name. Basically you need to do it in two steps, first figure out the meta-data (which tables are involved), then figure out the counts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know postgres well, but I am not aware of any way to do this in a single query. I also doubt there'll be a truly portable way, but the approach is similar.

Generally, I think you'd need to:

- Query system (meta) tables to find all foreign key table and column names.
- Use this to generate a (possibly massive) select query that counts all the `12`s